# C# Add doubles list to string array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working on a program in C# to show a string output (Won't say any more than that)
I have a doubles list containing the price of items, like this

```
private List<double> subTotals;
```

with double values added in using the .Add method.

I also have a string array to be the output, to display the item names plus the price.

My main question is, how would I go about adding items from my doubles list into my string array?

Comment: Nope, read it a couple of times, don't follow you?

Comment: Um, call `ToString()` on each `double` and then add that? It's not clear what you've tried and what the problem is. A [mcve] would really help. Note that you can't actually *add* to arrays - an array has a fixed size at initialization time.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use a string builder instead of a string array. Adding things to strings is a very heavy, wasteful process and using String Builder really helps keep your garbage cleaner happy. Have a quick google, I'm sure it will help.

Comment: That isn't necessarily true @Keithin8a. [The pre-compiler does a pretty good job at optimising these instances](https://ericlippert.com/2013/06/17/string-concatenation-behind-the-scenes-part-one/).

Comment: Does each item in the subTotals list have a matching item in the string Array? Are they in the same order? Are you just trying to append the subtotal on to each string in the array?
Also, saying "Won't say any more than that" in a question probably doesn't help with our understanding of what you want - we need as much information as possible.

Comment: You should create a class that holds the name and price.  Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx

Comment: @Liam That is interesting. I still think stringbuilder would be more efficient because it doesn't do any of the concatenation until the end (afaik). which means if you had ab = a+b and then abc = ab + c. that would be significantly less efficient no? But this is a conversation for another time, very good article you sent :)

Comment: @Keithin8a The downside of the stringbuilder is the overhead of creating a reference type upfront. Once it's created it's more efficent but the creation can be less efficent than just concatentaing some strings. anyhooooo

Answer (score 5):

An array has a fixed size, so you can't add items. Either make it also a `List<string>` or create a new `String[]` every time:

```
stringArray = stringArray 
    .Concat(subTotals.Select(d => d.ToString()))
    .ToArray();
```

You have a third option: [`Array.Resize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx), but it also creates a new array, just more efficient.

Comment: "fix" -> "fixed" :)

Comment: why would this be better than `var arr = subTotals.Select(d => d.ToString()).ToArray()`i don't get why the concat is there.

Comment: @KSib:I'm not a native english speaker so bear with me, but can't you use both?

Comment: @Franck: because OP mentioned that he wants to **add** the double-list to the array. Your approach would just replace it with the items in the list, but the old items are lost. But maybe that was just a misunderstanding ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'd definitely used "fixed". Sorry, English is weird sometimes. I figure you said "fix" because you're in present tense, but "fixed" is what you should use here. I couldn't explain it properly, but maybe it's a great question for the fine folks over here: http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Any native english speaker is invited to edit my answer to "fix" it :)

Comment: The reason why "fixed" is correct over "fix" is because the word "fix" can only be used as a verb or a noun ("Can you fix this?" or "That's a great fix"). The word "fixed" can be used as an adjective, verb, or adverb ("fixed position", "He fixed it", or "It is now fixed"). In your usage, it acts as an adjective, so that's why "fixed" must be used. English is weird haha :)

Comment: @kalamazoowho English definitely needs to be _fixed_ in order to be a _fixed_ language; do you have a proposed _fix_ that can be used to _fix_ it?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you couple the 2 items together in a class.  This way you only need 1 list and you can display either or both of the items from the list:

```
public class Item
{
    public string name = "";
    public double price = 0.0;
}
```